# Differentiation of inverse trigonometry function.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I'm given a function

$$y=8\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)-\frac{x\sqrt{16-x^2}}{2}$$

Can anyone give me some hints or guides how to differentiate it? Thanks. Because what I got from my working is

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}-\sqrt{16-x^2}\right)$$

The given answer in book is

$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$

It seems my answer is different with the given answer. Is there some short method to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ***It seems** my answer is different than the given answer.* - Appearances can be deceiving... ;-$)$

Comment: But my working is fairly wrong. :(. I'm still finding any shorter solution.

Comment: Try bringing all three terms to the same denominator, and see what happens.

Comment: I got it. Mind to share your method to solve this question? @Lucian

Comment: It's allowed and even encouraged to answer your own questions.

Comment: a change of variable $t = \sin^{-1}(x/4)$ is likely to make the computation a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{16}}}=\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}
$$